# How do we share our city upgrades to the region?

Tags: simcity-2013

We have started a region and had plans to build specific City Hall modules in our respective cities, so that the benefits would share between our cities. The same goes for things like Fire Trucks and Police Cars and the like.

None of our upgrades seem to "register" with other cities, and there doesn't appear to be any options for this. I'm assuming it's done automatically. We thought it had to do with the server issues, but the problem has been happening for over 24 hours, and other parts of the game seem to update fine (When we visit each other's cities, progress is up to date. We can actually see the City Hall modules that we're supposed to be sharing!).

Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated. We have no idea if we're doing something wrong or otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may still be a server issue, even my private game with no external players is not syncing instantly like it should. Townhall addons when placed apply to the region automatically same goes for the HQ for specializations (usually), there is nothing more that you need to do

Comment: For what it is worth, it actually worked for me on EU West tonight where I got the benefits of my buddy's town hall additions. Not sure on the delay involved though, but couldn't have been more than 30 minutes delay, if any at all.

Comment: If you notice when playing a game, the year never advances. Although in game time you progress in time, as far as the game is concerned, the year never does. My theory is that neighbor deals and other stuff that depend on annual updates never trigger since the year never changes. Most other things like local budget are processed monthly so you are able to see its effects.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that larger maps are actually composed of multiple smaller regions.  Your Town hall upgrades are shared with 3 or 4 other specific city plots - not all 15.